# why radio button is not behaving properly ??

Tags: html

This is short part of my code which display radio buttons.

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>

    <td style="text-align:center">
    <input type="radio" name="ah" value="" id="ah" align="left" checked="checked" />AH
    </td>

    <td style="text-align:center">
    <input type="radio" name="esp" value="none" id="esp" align="right"/>ESP
    </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that the one radio button (AH) is by default checked as mentioned here and when i click on other radio button it also gets checked 
but now both are checked how would I disable them.
I think it should happen automatically when I click on one radio button other button should be disabled automatically.
please correct me where am I wrong???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To group radio buttons together, they should share the same `name`:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>

    <td style="text-align:center">
    <input type="radio" name="someName" value="AH" id="ah" align="left" checked="checked" />AH
    </td>

    <td style="text-align:center">
    <input type="radio" name="someName" value="ESP" id="esp" align="right"/>ESP
    </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give both radio buttons the same `name` attribute so the browser can recognize them as being in the same group.

Comment: thanks Its working properly...Can u tell me is it possible to display html output here on stack overflow ???

Comment: @Udit you're welcome. Not sure what you mean by "HTML output" exactly? you mean rendered HTML? No, that's not possible: You'd have to use a service like http://jsfiddle.net instead

Answer (score 1):

They need to have the same `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

try this it will help.... you have to give the same name to both radio button

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>

    <td style="text-align:center">
    <input type="radio" name="esp" value="" id="ah" align="left" checked="checked" />AH
    </td>

    <td style="text-align:center">
    <input type="radio" name="esp" value="none" id="esp" align="right"/>ESP
    </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```